# How to respond to touches when the view is already pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitouch, uievent

I have two views in a ViewController that perform specific actions when touched down. If I keep one of them pressed with one finger and touch the same view with another finger, nothing happens. The "ok" test below doesn't appear.

I override the method `touchesBegan` to perform the actions:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    print("ok")
    if let touch = touches.first{
        let viewTag = touch.view!.tag
        if viewTag == 101 {
            // my action for view 1
        } else if viewTag == 102 {
            // my action for view 2
        }
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

## Edit

I'm already using `multipleTouchEnabled = true`

Comment: Was the `multipleTouchEnabled` property set as `true`?

Comment: Yes, in `viewDidLoad` I have `view.multipleTouchEnabled = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `multipleTouchEnabled = true` must be set in both views, not only the main one.

Put this code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
let tags = [101, 102]
for v in view.subviews {
    if tags.contains(v.tag) {
        v.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable multiple touches on your view:

```
self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

From Documentation:

**multipleTouchEnabled**

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver handles
>   multi-touch events.
>
> When set to YES, the receiver receives all touches associated with a
>   multi-touch sequence. When set to NO, the receiver receives only the
>   first touch event in a multi-touch sequence. **The default value of
>   this property is NO**.
>
> Other views in the same window can still receive touch events when
>   this property is NO. If you want this view to handle multi-touch
>   events exclusively, set the values of both this property and the
>   `exclusiveTouch` property to YES.